# What's the difference between "Es de mi X" and "Es mi X"?

Tags: traducción

What's the difference between "Es de mi X" and "Es mi X"; 
such as

> Es de mi hermano.

and

> Es mi hermano.

Comment: If you are Japanese, the "de" preposition in Spanish is somewhat equivalent to the の particle in Japanese (at least it is in this case). So, "mi hermano" is 私の弟 and "de mi hermano" is 私の弟の. Remember next time you ask a question to tell us what you think the difference is, so we will be able to write better answers.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. Yes, I'm Japanese and your explanation really helps for the Spanish learners of Japanese background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can translate "es de mi hermano" as "belongs to my brother", and "es mi hermano" as "is my brother"

"De" is a very common word in spanish with a lot of meanings, many of them can be translated directly to "of". Some of the most used:

- posession "es de mi hermano" = belongs to my brother
- filling "vaso de agua" = glass of water
- origin "soy de Mexico" = i'm from Mexico
- composition "cuchara de plata" = silver spoon
- topic "clase de matemáticas" = math lecture

Comment: Muchas gracias!!